# Multiple list shown in one webpart

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part

Trying to figure it out, how to create a web part with multiple lists? I got two lists for now. One is people on holidays other is people on business trip. I want to display those two lists in one web part, who is out office today. Maybe you guys have other ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Currently I am using SharePoint 2013

Comment: You want to use some out-of-the-box Webpart or to create your custom one? You could use Content Query Web Part (CQWP) to fetch items by content type. Create one base content type with fields in both types (holidays and business trip) and use CQWP. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/when-to-use-the-content-query-web-part-or-the-content-search-web-part-in-sharepoint-346a0f48-38de-409b-8a58-3bdca1768929

Comment: I need to display for now two lists. Who is on holidays and business trip. Either there is no CQWP or me being blind and can't find it

Comment: You need to enable **SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection feature**. Then you will see it in the **Content Rollup** category. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/when-to-use-the-content-query-web-part-or-the-content-search-web-part-in-sharepoint-346a0f48-38de-409b-8a58-3bdca1768929

Comment: It is enabled but I can't find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content Query web part will be what you're after... however, you are going against best practice and the web parts should be as context specific as possible. This means seperating them out

Comment: Yes, I do understand that. I need to somehow display multiple lists data in one place which will be displayed on the main TV.